# save value of spinner selected item using shared preference

Tags: android, spinner, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

How can I save the current selected spinner value, such that when I reopen the application the saved value is automatically selected by default?

My current code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);


     final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
         this, R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getBaseContext());
               SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
               prefEditor.putString("savedValue",spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

               String savedValue=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

               for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
               if(savedValue.equals(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()))
               {
                   spinner.setSelection(i);
                   break;
               }
           }
           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought what you want is-At some point,you want to show your saved value(comes from shared preference) in the spinner as selected item.For this

set spinner adapter with all the default values that includes your saved value.Now you want to show your saved value as selected.Suppose you have 6 items in the adapter

```
String savedValue=PreferenceManager
                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                     .getString("savedValue","");

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
if(savedValue.equals(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString())){
     spinner.setSelection(i);
     break;
}
```

To save spinner value at shared preference do this

```
 SharedPreferences prefs;
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
 prefEditor.putString("savedValue",spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
 prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: hi rasel actually i also want to know how to use shared preference for spinner pls can u explain it pls pls..

Comment: See the updated answer how to save your spinner value in shared preference

Comment: v v thanks rasel for help me...i am implementing it if i feel any problem i will asked u..i think it should be done now...

Comment: hello Rasel   pls see my updated code above  ..when i select any item from spinner and go back then when again i comes to that page then it is not showing previously selected value but first array value of spinner is showing ...where i am wrong..thanks

Comment: You are doing it in wrong way.When you have to save selected item in shared preference you have to save.And when you have to show your previously saved value in spinner then first you have to read value from shared preference then compare as i told to set your spinner by the saved item