# How to save the data of my Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In my application I have two activities.In first activity i have two spinners and when i set the spinner values in that and go for next Activity.When I return back to my first activity the data will be refreshed.What i want here is i want to see the vales that are set by privious.How i can do it.Please can any one help me.

Here my Activity life cycle called like bellow:

1)When I move from Activity1 to Activity2

onPause()

onStop()

2)When I return back to my first Activity

onStart()

onResume()

I have saved the values in onSaveInstance state but onRestoreInstance state is not called.here my code is:@Override

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        strAutoCompleteValue = autoPatientList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        strSpinnerAppointment = selectAppointment.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
        outState.putString("PatientName", strAutoCompleteValue);
        outState.putString("AppointmentDate", strSpinnerAppointment);

         Toast.makeText(this, "onSaved", 3000).show();
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        String pName = savedInstanceState.getString("PatientName");
        String appDate = savedInstanceState.getString("AppointmentDate");

       Toast.makeText(this, "onRestore", 3000).show();
    }
```

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Possible of duplicated question, check out this answer
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705277/save-value-of-spinner-selected-item-using-shared-preference)

Comment: You should rather use in `onSaveInstanceState`, for example `outState.putInt(String, spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())`. Next use Logger to log messages, not Toast, for example: `Log.i("Name of your tag", "Your message");`. And in `onRestoreInstanceState` you are not assigning your stored value to spinner, so for example you could use `spinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt(String))`.

Answer (score 1):

use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)
to save your spinner selection to a bundle. Then in `onCreate(Bundle)` when activity is recreated, get the data from the bundle to reset the spinners.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to program `Android` you should really look up the google documentation, as there is a lot of information about such common tasks. For example, this particular issue is covered here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You can also find sample code when you look at the [Shared Prefernces Section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save your state into Bundle and implement [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) or [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) to restore your state.

Comment: and inside onCraete, if you have savedInstanceState!=null then you are restoring the activity, otherwise it is a fresh activity.

Comment: this is also I tried but i get always savedInstanceState = null

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this

```
Spinner Spinner_ = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
 {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Spinner recent_Spinner = (Spinner) arg0;
Integer selected_Spinner_ = Spinner_.getSelectedItemPosition();
nw_global.set_Spinner_(selected_Spinner_.toString());
 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
if (nw_global.get_Spinner_() != null && !nw_global.get_Spinner_().isEmpty())
    {
        Spinner_.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(nw_global.get_Spinner_().replace("'", "")));
    } 
    else
    {
        Spinner_.setSelection(0);
    }
```

> And do this in nw_global

```
public class nw_global extends Application {

private static String scale_spinner;
public static void set_Spinner_(String i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    nw_global.scale_spinner = i;
}
public static String get_Spinner_(){

    return scale_spinner;
    }
 }
```

> Just sample code here .. Hope it'll work